# group by and order by making query very slow in mysql?

Tags: mysql, performance, order-by, group-by, query-performance

Query works fast:

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE 
  users.id, users.name 
from useres 
  left join user_statistics 
    on users.id = user_statistics.user_id 
where users.is_deleted = 0 
group by users.id 
order by users.updated_at 
  limit 50;
```

Slow Query:

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE 
  users.id, users.name,
  max(user_statistics.access_time) as user_access_time 
from useres 
  left join user_statistics 
    on users.id = user_statistics.user_id 
where users.is_deleted = 0 
group by users.id 
order by user_access_time 
  limit 50;
```

Explain plan of slow query

```
> *************************** 1. row ***************************
>            id: 1   select_type: SIMPLE
>         table: users
>          type: ref possible_keys: fk_users_is_deleted
>           key: fk_users_is_deleted
>       key_len: 4
>           ref: const
>          rows: 107696
>         Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
> *************************** 2. row ***************************
>            id: 1   select_type: SIMPLE
>         table: user_statistics
>          type: ref possible_keys: fk_user_statistics_user_id
>           key: fk_user_statistics_user_id
>       key_len: 4
>           ref: users.id
>          rows: 1
>         Extra:
```

I am using group by and order by on different tables. How can I optimize the above slow query?

Comment: Maybe the optimizer understands that in the first query the `left join user_statistics` is redundant and only the first table is needed.

Comment: I would imagine you are correct @ypercube . I know in SQL Server redundant joins are ignored by the optimizer

Comment: Any solution to fix this ?